# Slow SQL join on 5000 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have ran into a problem when I tried to check if there was a difference in the results between different tests. The inner select statement returns around 5000 rows but the join doesn't finish in one minute. I expect the output to be around 10 rows. Any reason that the join is so slow?

```
select * from(
           select *
           from R inner join C
           on R.i = C.j
           where C.j in (2343,3423,4222,1124,2344)
) AS A,(
           select *
           from R inner join C
           on R.i = C.j
           where C.j in (2343,3423,4222,1124,2344)
) AS B
where A.x = B.x and
A.y = B.y and
A.result <> B.result
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with aggregation:

```
select x, y, group_concat(distinct result) as results
from R inner join
     C
     on R.i = C.j
where C.j in (2343, 3423, 4222, 1124, 2344)
group by x, y
having count(distinct result) > 1;
```

For this query, an index on `C(j)` and `R(i)` would be very helpful.  I would add `x` and `y` to the appropriate index as well, but I don't know which table they are combing from.